# Word2vec with elasticsearch for texts similarity

Tags: elasticsearch, word2vec

I have a large collection of texts, where each text is rapidly growing. I need to implement a similarity search.

The idea is to embed each word as word2vec, and represent each text as a normalized vector by vector-adding the embeddings of each word in it. The subsequent additions to the text would only result in the refinement of the resultant text's vector by adding new word vectors to it.

Is it possible to use elasticsearch for  cosine similarity, by storing only the coordinates of each text's normalized vector in a document? If so, what's the proper index structure for such search?

Answer (score 7):

This [elasticsearch plugin](https://github.com/MLnick/elasticsearch-vector-scoring) implements a score function (dot product) for vectors stored using the [delimited-payload-tokenfilter](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/analysis-delimited-payload-tokenfilter.html)

The complexity of this search is a linear function of number of documents, and it is worse than tf-idf on a term query, since [ES first searches on an inverted index](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/inverted-index.html) then it [uses tf-idf for document scores](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/master/term-vs-full-text.html), so tf-idf is not executed on all the documents of the index. With the vector, the representation you're searching for is the vector space of the document with the lower cosine distance, without the advantages of the inverted index.

Comment: How does this scale with the number of documents? Is this much worse scalability-wise than tf-idf, that simply keeps an inverted index?

Answer (score 5):

For Elasticsearch 6.4.x StaySense has made [this plugin available](https://github.com/StaySense/fast-cosine-similarity).

Answer (score 4):

[Open Distro's elasticsearch](https://opendistro.github.io/for-elasticsearch/blog/odfe-updates/2020/04/Building-k-Nearest-Neighbor-(k-NN)-Similarity-Search-Engine-with-Elasticsearch/) recently has added knn_vector field to search by vector. Also recently [elatiknn](https://elastiknn.com/) plugin is developed to handle vector search in elastic.

But the searching is one part of the problem.
The other part is how to build good embeddings of your docs such that similar queries and docs be close to each other. For this purpose you can use sentence-bert. [txtai](https://github.com/neuml/txtai) is a nice tool that has implemented vector-search using senetence-bert which is very interesting.

Apart from that there is [Jina](https://jina.ai/) which is a complete solution for vector based semantic search in all kinds of media.

Answer (score 1):

Use txtai. It is more powerful.

To load dataset and build a txtai index

```
from datasets import load_dataset

from txtai.embeddings import Embeddings
from txtai.pipeline import Similarity

def stream(dataset, field, limit):
  index = 0
  for row in dataset:
    yield (index, row[field], None)
    index += 1

    if index >= limit:
      break

def search(query):
  return [(result["score"], result["text"]) for result in embeddings.search(query, limit=50)]

def ranksearch(query):
  results = [text for _, text in search(query)]
  return [(score, results[x]) for x, score in similarity(query, results)]

# Load HF dataset
dataset = load_dataset("ag_news", split="train")

# Create embeddings model, backed by sentence-transformers & transformers, enable content storage
embeddings = Embeddings({"path": "sentence-transformers/paraphrase-MiniLM-L3-v2", "content": True})
embeddings.index(stream(dataset, "text", 10000))

# Create similarity instance for re-ranking
similarity = Similarity("valhalla/distilbart-mnli-12-3")
```

For searching the dataset

```
from IPython.core.display import display, HTML

def table(query, rows):
    html = """
    <style type='text/css'>
    @import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Oswald&display=swap');
    table {
      border-collapse: collapse;
      width: 900px;
    }
    th, td {
        border: 1px solid #9e9e9e;
        padding: 10px;
        font: 15px Oswald;
    }
    </style>
    """

    html += "<h3>%s</h3><table><thead><tr><th>Score</th><th>Text</th></tr></thead>" % (query)
    for score, text in rows:
        html += "<tr><td>%.4f</td><td>%s</td></tr>" % (score, text)
    html += "</table>"

    display(HTML(html))

for query in ["Positive Apple reports", "Negative Apple reports", "Best planets to explore for life", "LA Dodgers good news", "LA Dodgers bad news"]:
  table(query, ranksearch(query)[:2])
```

Answer (score 0):

Dense vectors as a standalone field type are supported in newer versions of Elastic. [More here.](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/dense-vector.html)